# Detecting QTreeWidgetItem expansion

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a [`QTreeWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html) with [`QTreeWidgetItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html) for displaying a set of elements. Some of these elements have children, therefore,  they have the option of being collapsed or expanded by clicking the triangle next to the [`QTreeWidgetItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html) in the [`QTreeWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html). I need to detect when the user changes the expansion of the item. I've tried with [`QTreeWidget::itemChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemChanged) and [`QTreeWidget::itemClicked`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#itemClicked) but this is not called when the item is expanded. Any ideas on how to detect the user expansion of an item in the tree?

Comment: I think you have to handle `QTreeWidget::itemExpanded()` signal.

Comment: Depending on *why* you need to detect the expansion, you should have a look at the [fetch more example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-fetchmore-example.html).

Comment: Thank you! I did not see that signal. Sorry.